# Select specific value from an array javascript and remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

e.g.

```
a = [12, 213, 321, 312, 32, 42]
```

and i want to remove 213 from it

but i don’t ever know what order it will be in, in the array

How can I select it from the array and then also remove it?

Comment: How do you know you have to remove 213, not, 32 or 42? Does it come as an input from some source?

Comment: basically what i am doing is inserting these numbers into array a. And i know what in there and i know which one i need to remove. All I want to know is how i can select and remove 213. But not by selecting it like a[1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
array.splice(array.indexOf(213), 1);
```

Or if there is a possibility of having number which is not present in the array then you check it like this

```
var index = array.indexOf(213)
if(index > -1){
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: What happens when the given array have same values ? and some wants to delete that.Is this  code will work for all the possible values.

Comment: @Bharatsoni it will delete the first one which find in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` method to get index of element and can use `splice()` to remove that found element. eg:-

```
var array = a = [12, 213, 321, 312, 32, 42];
var index = array.indexOf(213);
//now remove this with splice method

if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the element, and use [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) or [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the index of the element in the array

```
a = [12, 213, 321, 312, 32, 42]
a.splice($.inArray(a, 213), 1)
```

Note: [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) was not used because of [IE compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

```
a.splice(a.indexOf(213),1)
```

or

```
var i = a.indexOf(213)
a = a.slice(i,i+1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the value with indexOf, then splice the array to remove the index.

Something like:

```
var idx = a.indexOf(213);
if (idx > -1) {
  a.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

Comment: Whoh, can't believe all these answers came in in the time it took to write mine! Now you have choices ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think there are two ways to accomplish that:

The easier way is simply iterating over the array and pushing all the values in it except the one you want to delete to another array. Then you could redefine the previous array variable as the new array.

Another way could be to use the splice method, but I'm not familiar with it.